# can not copy contents in email message to notepad.(Remote machine)

Tags: copy-paste

I can not copy contents in email message to notepad.(Remote machine)
I cleared the clip board and try again it.Though it clear the clipboard it doesn't work. Sometimes when I restart the machine(local) I would be able to copy content in remote machine.

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: How do you connect to remote machine?

Comment: via citrix software.

Comment: @wordpressm Maybe you should clarify... are you trying to copy from your local machine (email) **to** the remote (notepad)? Or is the email also on the remote and you just want to copy and paste within the remote? What keystrokes do you use to copy or do you use the mouse (right-click)?

Comment: I want to copy content in remote email to notepad. I tried both ctr+ c and right click option

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues in Citrix environment related to clipboard related to copy and paste.

Below i've listed some sites that can help you with this problem. Some solution you may skip (like changing the registry) because it sometimes works for you.
More likely it will be a program that starts and sits between the OS and the clipboard (like `RDPCLIP.EXE`) messing up your clipboard functionality.
(You can try this by ending the process `RDPCLIP.EXE` in the task-manager)

There is a program from Citrix, [Repair Clipboard Chain](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX106226), which repairs the clipboard functionality.

> The RepairCBDChain utility temporarily restores clipboard functionality. The order is restored by moving the ICA client to the beginning of the clipboard chain. If the offending application is launched after this repair utility has restored the clipboard order, the clipboard functionality may become corrupted again.

So if after running it your clipboard works, it might stop working again after a while and you need to find the offending program.

---

Article from Citrix Concepts: [Troubleshooting Clipboard Issue](http://citrixconcepts.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/troubleshooting-clipboard-issue/)

Citrix article about [Troubleshooting Client Clipboard Issues](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX086028)

[Google search for 'citrix copy and paste'](https://www.google.com/search?q=citrix+copy+and+paste)